# Does heist support substituting (strings / JSON) into an arbitrary location within a template?

Tags: haskell, heist

Regarding heist, I've got a template such as:

```
<script>
  var json = ???;
</script>
<h1>Example</h1>
```

Is there a way to substitute the `???` string with another string?

I think the following function might be the solution https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heist-1.0.1.0/docs/Heist-Splices-Json.html#v:bindJson but I have difficulty understanding that function and or what markup to use in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You cannot substitute anything inside a `<script>` tag because the text inside a script tag is not treated as HTML.  It's treated as plain text.  If this was not done, you wouldn't be able to write JS code like `if ( x < 42 )` because the less than would get treated as the beginning of a tag.